# How to embed .osm file (Open Street Map) to titanium android project?

Tags: javascript, android, dictionary, titanium, openstreetmap

i want to create an offline maps application with titanium and run it on android device..
After searching, i found this [android tiosm module](https://github.com/3ign0n/TiOpenStreetMap) on the internet and try to use it.. I try to build that module and embed that module to my application.. It works for me, but all i want is offline maps on android..

I search again and found that open street map can be exported into .osm file, but i can't embed it on my titanium android application.. Does anyone know how to embed .osm file to titanium, so i can create my offline maps application..

Many thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see TiOsm only supports [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), i.e. it just display pre-rendered images. For supporting `.osm` files it would have to include a renderer in order to produce tiles itself, which it doesn't. But there are lots of other [android apps for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) available. Some of them support rendering from `.osm` files or at least from converted `.osm` files.